# control php page by different user level logged in (not working)

Tags: php, authentication

Basically I try to make this code to navigate in a different php page..
Thi is verify_user.php

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "****", "myDB");
if (!$con){
    die("Connection to database failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$uname=$_POST['u_name'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];

$qry = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM login WHERE user='$uname'");

if(!$qry){
    die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
} else {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry);

        if($_POST['u_name'] == $row["user"] && $_POST['pass'] == $row["password"]) {
            if ($_POST['u_name'] = "admin") {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['u_name'];
                header("Location:admin_panel.php");
            } else {    
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['name']=$_POST['u_name'];
                header("Location:main.php");
            }       
        } else {
            header("Location:main.php?id=Worng ID / Password!");
        }
    }
    ?>
```

From this code as we can see, if the user is admin, it should go to admin_panel.php. And if the user is not admin, its should go to main.php.
For further explanation; thi is my admin_panel.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
   if(!$_SESSION['name']=='admin'){
?>



<!-- HTMML CODE -->



<?php
   }
   else
      header("Location:index.php?id=Only for admin.");
}
else
{
header("Location:index.php?id=Only for admin.");
}
?>
```

But its not working...

Comment: Two else? A header after the content? Read the docs first of all! And where's your question? Which code is not working?

Comment: $_POST['u_name'] = "admin" must be $_POST['u_name'] == "admin"

Comment: admin id & password : admin

Comment: @wumm when i log into the system, it keeps staying in login page

Comment: Are you really sure there is no output before the `header()` (even a white space is an output!)

Comment: @wumm yes, but in my original code (before i decide to add admin page), only have if and else -- that one is working very well

Comment: if($_POST['u_name'] == $row["user"] && $_POST['pass'] == $row["password"]) {
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['name']=$_POST['u_name'];
  $uname = $_POST['u_name'];
  header("Location:main.php");
 } else {
  header("Location:main.php?id=Password / ID Wrong.");
 }

Comment: header("Location:index.php?id=" . urlencode('Only for admin'));

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages? Try turning them on with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the first line of your code.

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: @wumm where should i put that code? and where can i see that error message?

Comment: Put it in the admin login code in the first line. The error messages should appear on your site, if you open it in the browser.

Comment: Try using else with error messages..

Comment: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
if ($_POST['u_name'] = "admin") {
```

To

```
if ($_POST['u_name'] == "admin") {
```

Change

```
 if(!$_SESSION['name']=='admin'){
```

To

```
 if($_SESSION['name']=='admin'){
```

In fact you could change

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
   if(!$_SESSION['name']=='admin'){
?>



<!-- HTMML CODE -->



<?php
   }
   else
      header("Location:index.php?id=Only for admin.");
}
else
{
header("Location:index.php?id=Only for admin.");
}
?>
```

To

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['name']) && $_SESSION['name'] == 'admin'){
?>



<!-- HTMML CODE -->



<?php
}
else
{
header("Location:index.php?id=Only for admin.");
}
?>
```

Also, this really isn't great

```
header("Location:index.php?id=Only for admin.");
```

You shouldn't have spaces in an url

And BTW this code would be vulnerable to SQL injections.